# How to call native exe function (visual basic 6.0) From .NET (C#)?

Tags: c#, .net, vb6, com-interop, unmanaged

We have an exe file produced by visual basic 6.0 (unmanaged exe) and a .NET .exe written with C#.

How can I call a function in unmanaged exe (visual basic) from CLR .exe?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have access to the VB6 code or is all you have an exe?

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can see that working is if the VB6 executable has a COM interface, in which case you should be able to call it from a .Net app.

This article might be helpful: [How To Create a DCOM Client/Server Application by Using Visual Basic](http://support.microsoft.com/?id=266717)

Answer (score 1):

If you can modify the VB6 application, then the most obvious way is to start VB6 app via command line, pass parameters via command line and get result via exit code or via console output. The vb6 application should be modified to handle the parameters accordingly.